# Maven Dependency Issue - javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0.2 (Does not exist)

Tags: java, spring, maven-3, spring-tool-suite

I am having very strange issue, one of my component is looking for spring dependency which does not even exists and it is happening for only my machine,  my counter parts are having no issue running the same code base. Even CI tool also works fine.

Error :

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.xml.stream:stax-api:**jar:1.0.2**: Could not transfer artifact javax.xml.stream:stax-api:**pom:1.0.2** from/to spring-release

Version Used :
Java
java version "1.6.0_41"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

Maven
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:2
3+05:30)
```

pom snippet

it is configured to look for **1.0-2**

Any suggestions genius minds around the world. ??

Comment: Did u try to check from where the dependency is getting downloaded using mvn dependency:tree. May be from some external systems it is getting downloaded.

Comment: It seems that the build looks in only one repository, spring-release one. Is there any other repositories defined in your pom?